# How to display a MessageBox to the logged on user from SYSTEM account?

Tags: c, windows

I want to create an application, which will query the free space from C:\ and if it is lower then a limit, it should show a messagebox to the user, that he/she should free up some space on C:. This application would run under the SYSTEM account. My problem is that this messagebox is not visible to the logged on user. So my question is how can i show a messagebox to the logged on user from SYSTEM account? If someone could provide some example code, i would be very thankfull.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to this question would largely depend on the actual system you are using. Differences are mainly related to session separation introduced in Vista and to Terminal Services (also on 2003). What system are you talking about? Also, you should avoid this kind of thing by all means, since it is a security risk. Search the web for "shatter attack".

Comment: why are running something on the SYSTEM account (that is a pretty big security risk) ? For what you describe it would suffice to just make a normal Windows Service plus a tray app (running via AutoStart or similar in the session of the logged-in user) - they communicate via IPC (for example shared memory) and the tray app shows the messagebox or whatever is needed...

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I want to do this under XP and Windows 7. Yes i know that this isn't "best" solution, but if you have a better a idee then share with me please. I don't have :(

Comment: @Yahia: The reason why i use SYSTEM is pretty simple. I needed something whith i can run application and scripts on every PC. So i made a policy, which will install a scheduled task on every computer when the pc starts. This scheduled task runs in every hour, and calls a .vbs which will wait random minutes, and after that it will call a batch file, where the applications which i want run are listed, and it will be executed.

Comment: Although `Administrator` is a big security risk but it is still better than using `SYSTEM`... BTW running a scheduled task is possible with a logged-on user too... so why not run these directly in the logged-on user session ?

Comment: @Yahia: do you mean when the user logs on, then should i run my application in his session? Or how do you mean?

Comment: @Yahia: i thought about this too, but i have a problem with that. Users often do that they logged in, and then just they lock the pc. And the pc will restart only then when some patches will be isntalled, which can be 3 weeks. So in 3 weeks when i use this method my application will run only once!

Comment: NO - I mean create the "scheduled task" in that user account... so the scheduled task runs inside the user session

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a seperated user interface, try to search for interprocess communication, like Yahia mentioned, thats not the safe way to go. However there is TerminalServices API doing the session switch for you, right now the user would get some notification in taskbar but no user interface at all, thats right.